# Construct a function to meet given requirements and constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Assume there is a scalar function of two variables: $F(A,B) = \frac{B}{A}$, such that
$B \in [0;10], A \in [B;50]$, and assume $C_{max} = A_{max}-B_{min} \Rightarrow C_{max} = 50$

1. When $A-B \to C_{max}$ function $F$ returns result which is desirable.
2. When $A-B \to 0$ function $F$ returns result which is undesirable.

My goal is to find function $F_f(A,B)$ such that:

1. When $A-B \to C_{max}$ function $F_f$ returns result as close as possible to $F$.
2. When $A-B \to 0$ function $F_f$ returns result as close as possible to $0$.

I was not able to find any idea or hint how to solve it, though my guess it might be some kind of optimization technique.

How can I "shape" the original $F(A,B)$ to "drive" it to $F_f(A,B)$?

Comment: Are there any restriction on $F_f$? For instance one can define $f$ in a piecewise manner: $f(A,B;N)=A^2$ if $A>B$, $f(A,B;N)=N$ if $A\leq B$. Then take $\lim_{N\to\infty}f(A,B;N)$ and you get the desired result.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez I've updated constraint on $F_f$. Your proposal would work only when $A \approx A_{max}$ and $B \approx B_{max}$. Also I would prefer continious $F_f$ over piecewise.

Comment: I am not sure that I follow the problem, do you have any reference?